# Cross-thread invalid operation exception but only one thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Basically a `FileSystemWatcher` changes a property of a list item which causes the `List_Changed` event to be fired:

```
void sounds_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    UnsafedChanges = true;
    Gui.soundsDataGridView.AutoResizeColumns();
}
```

The exception is thrown here:

```
private bool unsafedchanges = false;
public bool UnsafedChanges
{
    get
    {
        return unsafedchanges;
    }
    set
    {
        unsafedchanges = value;
        if (!value)
            Gui.Text = soundsXMLFilePath;
        else
            Gui.Text = " * " + soundsXMLFilePath; // thrown here
    }
}
```

where `Gui` is the main form of my windows forms application, given to the class this code is in by the constructor.

`soundsXMLFilePath`:

```
public string soundsXMLFilePath {
    get{
        return soundsxmlfilepath;
    }
    set{
        bool changed = soundsxmlfilepath != value;
        soundsxmlfilepath=value;
        if (changed)
            Gui.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Now I know about `Invoke`, the thing is that I don't understand why the exception is thrown: By my understanding, there is just the main thread since I can not think of one being started somewhere. The `FileSystemWatcher` raises a event, a property is changed which causes the `List_Changed` to be called which again just sets a property, in which eventually the text of the `Form` object is set. Where is the second thread here?

Thank you.

Comment: Try this: set make sure your debugger breaks on exceptions (Debug > Exceptions, check the "Thrown" column on "Common Language Runtime Exceptions") and when the exception gets thrown, look at the "debug > windows > threads".  Does it show multiple threads, and more importantly, is the debugger stopped on a non-ui thread (the UI thread is "Main Thread")?

Comment: I think FileSystemWatcher notifies you using a thread from the thread pool.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are asking is explained here [FileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.synchronizingobject(v=vs.110).aspx).

> **Remarks**
>   When SynchronizingObject is null, methods handling the Changed, Created, Deleted, and Renamed events are called on a thread from the system thread pool. For more information on system thread pools, see ThreadPool.

It also contains the solution - just set it to your form or some control on it, like this

```
// inside a form
yourFileSystemWatcher.SynchronizingObject = this;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Windows Form has a thread and the FileSystemWatcher has a thread - two threads.

Comment: This answer needs improvement.  A resource?  An explanation as to why it uses different threads?

Comment: Well, that's disappointing.  His direct question was:  "Where is the second thread here?"  Do accurate, if succinct, answers really deserve a -1?  Perhaps all VGD needed to know was his actual question answered?  (In my defense, Ivan's answer was not present when I submitted mine, and I would take his over mine.)

Comment: @MichaelGorsich -- Well, you've convinced me that your answer doesn't deserve a down vote.  However, my vote appears to be "locked" since I put it in "too long ago" -- a feature of Stack Overflow that annoys me.  At any rate, I can't change my vote unless you edit your question.

Comment: @Rory: Sorry if I came off bad-attitude.  I really was just trying to answer the question.      Reza:  Appreciate the comment  : )

Comment: @MichaelGorsich -- No you didn't have a bad attitude, and your comment seriously made me think.  I couldn't find a good reason why a succinct answer was "not useful" (the popup hint you get when you hover over the down vote button) as long as it answered the question and didn't provide incorrect or misleading information.

Comment: @MichaelGorsich You can edit your answer and change filesystemwatcher to `FileSystemWatcher` and then inform roryap, then since your answer is edited, roryap can undownvote the answer :)